# La computadora se cuelga al hacer una regresión con correlación espacial y variable aleatoria

Tags: r

El codigo que utilice es el que puse en la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta no es la forma correcta de realizar las preguntas te aconsejo que des un vistazo a como hacerlo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola @wilson carrillo Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.